# How to use cloned github repository classes into existing java project

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am using some classes from a github project. I created a maven project and added the dependency from the provided github project, but I need to change some code in those project classes.

I have downloaded and modified the repository but now I have no idea how to import it and use the classes to my existing project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should create a GitHub account and fork the repository. The new fork is your personal version for any changes you wish to make.

Comment: Try to get help using google, and also watch this url: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/EclipseMavenInt.html

Comment: It is a little unclear what you want to use the classes for. You can either import the repository using the Maven plugin for your IDE of choice or else just copy in the classes that you want into the current project you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have built your modified github project, you can install it in your local maven repository.

Just use this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

If you have built it with a different version, you now just have to reference this new version in your pom.xml file.